# Entity Framework Core 2.0 FromSql and SQL Injection

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, sql-injection

I need to know the correct way to handle SQL Injection when using the FromSQL command.

At runtime, I need to dynamically create a where statement.  So I am using FromSql to create the SQL command.  Now I know that using use string interpolation is the way to go.  However, I need to step through a list of "Where Parameters" to generate the command.  Simple enough to do;

```
foreach (var x in wp)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(results))
        results = $"{results} and {x.Field} = {x.Value}";
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(results))
       results = $"where {x.Field} = {x.Value}";
}
```

Problem is that this return a simple string and would not be string interpolation.  How can I do this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entityframework will parameterize your queries if you put it in the following format:

```
db.something.FromSql("SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE AuthorId = {0}", id)
```

Is x.Field a form field that has a fixed number of possibilities? i.e. title, firstname etc. If so then something like the following:

```
        var sqlstring = new StringBuilder();
        var sqlp = new List<SqlParameter>();

        var i = 0;
        foreach (var x in wp)
        {
            var param = "@param" + i.ToString();
            if (i!=0)
            {
                sqlstring.Append($" AND {x.Field} = " + param);
                sqlp.Add(new SqlParameter(param, x.Value));
            }
            if (i==0)
            {
                sqlstring.Append($"WHERE {x.Field} = " + " @param" + i.ToString());
                sqlp.Add(new SqlParameter(param, x.Value));
            }
            i++;
        }
```

You'd then need to do something like this:

```
db.something.FromSql(sqlstring.ToString(), sqlp.ToArray())
```

Might be a better/cleaner way but that should work.

Comment: Thanks!  I basically came up with your solution just without the StringBuilder.  The problem was that the IDE actually gave a SQL injection warning.  Your solution does not

Answer (score 1):

My solution to this problem is a VS extension, [QueryFirst](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bbsimonbb.QueryFirst#overview). QueryFirst generates a C# wrapper for sql that lives in a .sql file. As such, parameters are the only way to get data into your query and SQL injection is near impossible. There are numerous other advantages: you edit your sql in a real environment, it's constantly validated against your db, and using your query in your code is very simple.

Comment: I have moved from this problem but that looks exactly like what I wanted.  Hope I can circle back and use this